# Windows 7 program compatibility privilege level

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to set the compatibility of some programs in Windows 7 so that they always run as administrator, no matter who is logged in.

I've tried setting this via the "Compatibility" tab of the programs' properties. More specifically, I have clicked the "Change settings for all users" button and then checked the "Run this program as an administrator" box.

The problem is that whatever changes I make never get reflected in the first dialog window after I click "Okay" in the second. The box always remains unchecked. I can never tell if the setting has been enabled or not.

Why does it do this? Is there something I can do to get it to work? Thanks.

Windows 7 x64 SP1

Comment: You can't do that. It would be a big security hole.

Comment: A few video games are a big deal? Then why show the setting in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Only non-system applications and processes can be selected to always run with administrator privileges.  Applications marked to run as administrator will not launch properly when initiated from standard accounts.  Any changes you make in contradiction to this will not be accepted by the system, and this is probably why the box remains unchecked.

You can read the article below to see what is possible, but you will have to accept that some applications will never run automatically with admin privileges in Genuine Windows 7.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx

Comment: They're just some video games. And the setting *does* work. It's just not shown properly in the dialog.

Comment: Ok, well games are certainly non-system applications so no problems there.  You should however still be prompted to allow the application if it is making changes that require administrator privileges.  Out of interest, why do the games need to be run as administrator?  Do they not run otherwise?

Comment: I do get prompted. However, the dialog doesn't reflect this.